# Change size based on value

Tags: jquery, css

Here is my code:

```
var changeValue = document.getElementById("fontSize");
changeValue.value= 400;

var changeSign = document.getElementById("Box");
changeSign.style.width = ?;
```

I would like to change the box width based on the `"fontSize"` value, in this case 400.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're asking for?
`changeSign.style.width = changeValue.value + 'px'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to change the box width WHEN the value is changed.

In this case you need an Event:

```js
var changeValue = document.getElementById("fontSize");
    changeValue.value= 100;
    changeValue.onchange = function(){
    var changeSign = document.getElementById("Box");
    changeSign.style.width = this.value+'px';
    };
```

```html
 <input id='fontSize'>
    <div id='Box' style="background-color: red; width: 100px; height: 100px">
```

You could also:

- Create a button
- Attach another event